# October CMS Theme CSS

Tags: laravel, php-7, octobercms

I am new to use October cms but everything goes well until I change css.

Create a navbar with a class (.navtest) that is located in the theme.css / assets folder. Added a background: red;

To see something happening, have also tried with !important but no things happen. have tried to change css / bootstrap.css that comes with demo theme but nothing happens then either.

So I do not know what I'm doing wrong. Is it someone who has a solution?

Thanks

Comment: hmm can you share theme name and are you sure your are changing same theme file which is active theme for frontend.

Answer (score 0):

October allows you to combine CSS in bundles, these bundles can be cached in production. Try clearing your cache, for example with 
 https://octobercms.com/plugin/romanov-clearcachewidget